# mpdf - перенос строк в шапке таблицы

Tags: html, mpdf

При формировании таблицы в mpdf необходимо развернуть текст в шапке и в заданных местах перенести. Вот пример кода:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th style="text-rotate: 90"><p>Line1</p><p>Line2</p></th>
<th style="text-rotate: 90">Line1<br/>Line2</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Однако стандартные тэги для переноса текста в данном случаи перестают функционировать. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли какое-нибудь решения для переноса слов ?

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам надо повернуть абзацы с текстом на 90 градусов, то для этого существует transform:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
p {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
p:last-child {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th><p>Line1</p><p>Line2</p></th>
<th><p>Line1</p><p>Line2</p></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Увы, не сработало. Видимо этот стиль не поддерживается.